# Import Javascript Function Into Vue's index.html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In `test.js` I have

```
function test() {
   console.log("testing");
}
```

In `index.html` I have

```
<head>
  <script src="../src/test.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>test()</script>
</body>
```

Seems pretty straightforward to me, but every time I run this I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined` Am I crazy? What is going on here? Is webpack doing something crazy that I'm not understanding?

Comment: You cant use <script>-tags within the <template>-tags in Vue. It's a Vue thing. You have to move it to the JS section between the ordinary <script>-tags.

Comment: This `index.html` isn't a vue file though? I'm able to import other scripts with the `<script>` tag in this file.

Comment: I guess, the question is tagged as [vue.js] by accident. Since the question text itself doesn't hint any involvement of Vue.

Comment: I added the vue tag because I thought maybe the structure of Vue might be causing the issue

Comment: _`type="text/babel"`_ . Try `type="text/javascript"` or no `type` attribute at all

Comment: In order to call `window.test()` from your inline script, you need to assign the function `test` in module `../src/test.js` to `window.test`. i.e. `window.test = test`

Comment: @Phil Good point. \@Dallin Do you use a transcompiler?

Comment: @spender I see no modules

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly load `.js` files from the `src` directory.

If you have a plain old `.js` file that you want to include in your `index.html` file, put in in [the `public` folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) and include it like this

```html
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>test.js"></script>
```

Files in the `public` folder are directly copied into `dist` when building your Vue app (via the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/)). The `dist` folder is like the document root of your app; web-based requests for assets like those in your `.html` file cannot be made to resources outside of that root.

Files in `src` are bundled by being included via your app's [entry point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) (eg `src/main.js`). Webpack builds the bundle, places it in the `dist` directory and injects the appropriate `<script>` tags into your `.html` files via the [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/).

---

You definitely don't want `type="text/babel"` either. That will cause the browser to ignore your `<script>` element since it does not know what to do with that [mime type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#textjavascript)...

> using any MIME type other than `text/javascript` may result in scripts that do not load or run.

Comment: The thread owner didn't state their directory structure. We shouldn't assume the kind of content that might be inside `src/`

Comment: @shaedrich spending 2 hours trying to get all the details is annoying too. Phil can make a long shot and good if it's a hit, otherwise OP can move forward still. Assumptions here are not a big deal IMO.

Comment: @shaedrich it's irrelevant. Static assets (scripts, styles, images, etc) included directly from `index.html` cannot be served from any directory other than `public`. Do you not think I tested this? Because I did

Comment: @shaedrich The only assets from other directories like `src` that get included are those bundled and they would need to be done so via the entry-point (`src/main.js`).

Comment: @Phil you are amazing! I would have never figured this out. I would give you 10 upvotes if I could. Could you help me understand why my script has to be in the public folder?

Comment: @DallinDavis I've updated my answer with some extra information